# How can I convert from a curly bracket list to the list head and tail in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, brackets, square

I am trying to use `=..` in Prolog to convert between list formats.

So far, I have used:

```
{[t,a],[t,b],[t,c]} =.. A.
A = [{},  ([t, a], [t, b], [t, c])].
```

How can I convert from `{[t,a],[t,b],[t,c]}` to the list head `[t, a]` and tail `[[t, b], [t, c]]` in Prolog?

i.e.

```
curly_head_taila({[t,a],[t,b],[t,c]},Head,Tail).

Head = [t, a],
Tail = [[t, b], [t, c]].
```

Prolog doesn't allow `{[t,a],[t,b],[t,c]}={Head|Tail}.`

I am creating type converters from one format to another and would like to write an interpreter in Prolog, which converts between bracket formats more easily than Prolog.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by creating a predicate that converts conjunction to list (and vice versa):

```
conjunction_list(C, [C])   :- not(C = (_,_)).
conjunction_list(C, [P|R]) :- C = (P,Q), conjunction_list(Q, R).
```

Examples:

```
?- conjunction_list((a,b,c), L).
L = [a, b, c].

?- conjunction_list(C, [a,b,c]).
C =  (a, b, c) ;
false.
```

Then you can use that predicate to do the desired conversion:

```
curly_square({}, []).
curly_square({C}, L) :- once(conjunction_list(C, L)).
```

Examples:

```
?- curly_square({[t,a], [t,b], [t,c]}, L), L = [H|T].
L = [[t, a], [t, b], [t, c]],
H = [t, a],
T = [[t, b], [t, c]].

?- curly_square({a,b,c}, S).
S = [a, b, c].

?- curly_square(C, [a,b,c]).
C = {a, b, c}.

?- curly_square({[t, a], [t, b]}, S).
S = [[t, a], [t, b]].

?- curly_square(C, [[t, a], [t, b]]).
C = {[t, a], [t, b]}.
```

**Remark** Predicate `once/1` prevents backtracking and is defined as follows:

```
once(Goal) :- call(Goal), !.
```

Answer (score -1):

You can convert from curly to square brackets in Prolog as follows:

Checks the list elements:

```
t_or_empty([t,_]).
t_or_empty({[t,_]}).
t_or_empty([]).
```

Converts from curly brackets to the head and tail of the list in square brackets:

```
curly_head_taila(Head1,C1,C2) :-

 Head1 =.. [{}, Round_bracket_list],
 
 curly_head_tail1a(Round_bracket_list,[],[Head1a|Head1b]),
 
 (Round_bracket_list =.. [{}, _]-> (square_to_curly(Head1a,C1),
 (Head1b=C2))
 ;
 [Head1a|Head1b]=[C1|C2]),!.
```

Converts round brackets (in above) to square brackets, i.e. `curly_head_tail1a(([t,a],[t,b],[t,c]),[],A). A = [[t, a], [t, b], [t, c]].`

```
curly_head_tail1a(T,List1,List2) :- t_or_empty(T),append(List1,[T],List2),!.

curly_head_tail1a(Round_bracket_list,List1,List2) :-
 curly_head_taila(Round_bracket_list,List3,List4),
 append(List1,[[List3|List4]],List2).

curly_head_tail1a(Round_bracket_list,List1,List2) :-
 
 Round_bracket_list =.. [',', T,  B],

 append(List1,[T],List3),
 (B=..[{}, _]->append(List3,[B],List2);
 curly_head_tail1a(B,List3,List2)),!.
```

Used above, and which can be used separately, converts square to curly brackets, i.e. `square_to_curly([[t,a],[t,b]],B). B = {[t, a], [t, b]}.`

```
square_to_curly(A,B) :-
 square_to_round(A,C),round_to_curly(C,B).
```

Converts round to curly brackets, i.e. `round_to_curly(([t,a],[t,b],[t,c]),B). B = {[t, a], [t, b], [t, c]}.`

```
round_to_curly(A,B) :-
 B=..[{},A].
```

Finally, converts square to round brackets, i.e. `square_to_round([[t, a], [t, b], [t, c]],B). B =  ([t, a], [t, b], [t, c]).`

```
% square_to_round([1,2,3],A).                   
% A = (1, 2, 3).

square_to_round(A,C) :-
 ((A=[D]
 )->
 C=(D);
 (A=[D|E],
 square_to_round(E,F),
 C=..[',',D,F])),!.
```